# How can Raspberry Pi output a HD stream? How is graphic processing handled in Linux and Raspberry Pi 's hardware?

Tags: hardware, video, hdmi, linux

Raspberry Pi has something less than decent hardware and is still able to output an HD stream (that's what I have read, correct me if I am wrong). A 700 MHz [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) processor, a not-so-great GPU, but it still manages to have an HD output.

Which parts of the graphic processing are handled by different subsystems ([CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit), [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit), external monitor)? What is the load of generating a HD output on different subsystems as compared to the older analog output?
Additionally, if Raspberry Pi is attached to a big HD screen, will the output be bad (as more number of pixels have to be processed)?

Some reference to the Linux graphic stack (I think I can handle some amount of technicality) will be appreciated.

Comment: To my understanding it is the other way around.  It is a custom media player chip which just happens to have a CPU capable of running Linux somewhere in a corner.

Comment: The RPi uses a VideoCore 4 GPU, which is the latest standard being used by Broadcom. It's basically the same GPU found in many Samsung Galaxy devices. It does a lot of hardware processing of video instead of software processing which makes it significantly faster. The VCore4 is capable of 24GFLOPs...which is equivalent and better than some Core 2 Duos-(24GFLOPS means 24,000,000,000 floating point operations per sec.  yes, billion, per second), and this is just the GPU, not including the CPU. Another advantage, Linux, much more efficent than Windows and all the bloatware people put on.

Answer (score 4):

> Raspberry Pi has something less than decent hardware and is still able to output an HD stream (that's what I have read, correct me if I am wrong). A 700  MHz ARM processor, a not-so-great GPU, but it still manages to have an HD output.

The Raspberry Pi has an incredibly powerful GPU, especially for its price.  Sporting a [VideoCore IV GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VideoCore) in the [BCM2835 SoC](http://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835), it can easily output HD [1080p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p) video. And because the chip is cost-optimized and designed for power efficiency, it was the perfect choice for the Raspberry Pi.

Chips like these are being used in many higher-end devices today (such as smartphones), some being the [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) of choice for companies such as Apple.

---

The reason you might think that the Raspberry Pi has less than decent hardware is because few applications actually use [hardware acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration) with the Raspberry Pi ([it actually uses the CPU to process graphics right now](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8674/8631)).  One program I know does use hardware acceleration and runs very well is [OMXPlayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer). Try it out, and you can see how powerful the Raspberry Pi can actually be when properly used.